# Limpiar texto de una tabla

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente tabla estática, donde realizo un ajax y obtengo data. 
En mi success ajax pregunto si la array tiene datos me llene la tabla.

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%"></td>
            <td width="25%">Usuario 1</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="fila1">
            <td>Activacion</td>
            <td data-name="Nombre" class="Nombre editable" data-type="select2"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="fila2">
            <td>Asistencia o Cotizacion Simple</td>
            <td data-name="Nombre" class="Nombre editable" data-type="select2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="fila3">
            <td>Calculo Precio</td>
            <td data-name="Nombre" class="Nombre editable" data-type="select2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="fila4">
            <td>Diseño (planos clientes)</td>
            <td data-name="Nombre" class="Nombre editable" data-type="select2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="fila5">
            <td>Gestion de Venta</td>
            <td data-name="Nombre" class="Nombre editable" data-type="select2"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Pero si busco denuevo con otro numero y el array esta vacio que este limpie la tabla.

```
        $.ajax({
                url: 'JSON.php',
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    nro_pi: nro_pi
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                    if (!$.isArray(data) || !data.length) {

                     //BORRAR DATOS DE TABLA
                    } else {

                      //MUESTRA DATOS
                },
                error: function() {

                }
            });
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como remover las filas de la tabla con jQuery.

```js
$('#boton').click(function() {
  $('#table1 .editable').empty();
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Usuario 1</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="fila1">
            <td>Activacion</td>
            <td class="editable">Prueba</td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="fila2">
            <td>Asistencia o Cotizacion Simple</td>
            <td class="editable">Prueba</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="fila3">
            <td>Calculo Precio</td>
            <td class="editable">Prueba</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="fila4">
            <td>Diseño (planos clientes)</td>
            <td class="editable">Prueba</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="fila5">
            <td>Gestion de Venta</td>
            <td class="editable">Prueba</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<button id="boton">Limpiar</button>
```

Comment: Deseo poder eliminar el texto de la tabla

Comment: ¿Las filas son fijas entonces?

Comment: Si solo que limpie el text del 2 `TD`

Comment: Lo actualicé, como las celdas de la tabla tienen una clase específica puedes aprovechar eso para seleccionarlas y limpiar solo su contenido.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').text('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%"></td>
            <td width="25%">Usuario 1</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="fila1">
            <td>Activacion</td>
            <td data-name="Nombre" class="Nombre editable" data-type="select2">datos</td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="fila2">
            <td>Asistencia o Cotizacion Simple</td>
            <td data-name="Nombre" class="Nombre editable" data-type="select2">datos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="fila3">
            <td>Calculo Precio</td>
            <td data-name="Nombre" class="Nombre editable" data-type="select2">datos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="fila4">
            <td>Diseño (planos clientes)</td>
            <td data-name="Nombre" class="Nombre editable" data-type="select2">datos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="fila5">
            <td>Gestion de Venta</td>
            <td data-name="Nombre" class="Nombre editable" data-type="select2">datos</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Podrías hacerlo con esa sencilla línea de **Jquery**. Lo que haces es ponerle contenido vacío a los `td` que sean segundo hijo de un `tr` que sea hijo del `tbody`.